# Higher order function parameters with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, currying

I am trying to make a higher order function (not sure if theres a better name for this) that can generically take any function with any arguments, which returns a new function that has the same input arguments along with another.

For example, if I have a function:

```js
function func1(arg1: number, arg2: string) {
  return `${arg1}${arg2}`
}
```

I want to be able to pass it into a function like so:

```js
const func2 = hof(func1);
// type of func2 should be: (arg1: number, arg2: string, arg3: number) => string
func2(1, "test", 2);
```

I have tried writing `hoc` like:

```js
function hof<P, T>(fn: (...params: P) => T): T {
  return (...params, arg: number) => {
    // ... do some extra stuff using the extra `arg`
    return fn(...params);
  }
}
```

which doesn't seem quite right. I don't think I want to actually be spreading the `params` into the array, since I want my generated function to take the original arguments just like they were in the given function (not as an array).

Is this possible to make Typescript give me an inteligent response/type for this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrXllW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply, pls mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: This smells a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @jcalz its not ideal but it does work. The function's intellisense type is now `(args_0: number, args_1: string, args_2: number) => string`, so unfortunately the parameter names get lost making it less self-documenting

Comment: The best I can do is [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRXkEm) where the final argument has a hardcoded name like `numArg`; I don't see how you could ever get "arg3" as the name, TS can't generate labels on command like that. Does that work for you? If so I'll write it up (although @caTS's answer is quite similar, I think). Let me know (ping via @jcalz pls)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a mess to do so but yes, probably similar to:

```
function hof<A extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>, R>(fn: (...params: A) => R) {
    return (...args: [...params: A, arg: number]) => {
        const [arg, ...params] = [args[args.length - 1], ...args.slice(0, -1)] as [arg: number, ...params: A];
        return fn(...params);
    };
}
```

It only looks this janky because rest parameters cannot be first. So I had to make the type `[...params: A, arg: number]` instead and then destructure that inside the body.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WPpYeW)

Comment: ... reverse?! [What are you doing?](https://tsplay.dev/mMBekW) 

Comment: Whoops... Guess I was too focused on making the types work I forgot to make it work at runtime...

Answer (score 0):

```
function hof<T extends (...args: [number, string, ...any[]]) => any>(
  fn: T
): (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> {
  return (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
    const [arg0, arg1] = args;

    return fn(...([arg0, arg1, ...args] as const));
  };
}
```

Hope this solution will help

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**